# Can we debug the goldfish kernel 3.4 of the default SDK Android emulator running on Windows? (i.e. by a break-point)

Tags: linux, debugging, android-emulator

I need to know if we can add a break-point inside the goldfish kernel and monitor some variable. Please note that I am using a Linux machine to cross compile both the emulator and goldfish kernel 3.4 (fetched from AOSP) - Also as I said, emulator is a .exe process running on Windows

Answer (score 1):

I spent a couple of days searching for an answer for this question and I figured out that it is possible, and here is the answer:

**Compilation goldfish 3.4 to turn the debugging options in kernel configuration file**

Get prebuilt toolchain

> cd ~
>
> git clone https://android.googlesource.com/platform/prebuilts/gcc/linux-x86/arm/arm-eabi-4.6

Setting env vars for the prebuilt toolchain by appending the following env vars to ~/.bashrc

> gedit ~/.bashrc
>
> export ARCH=arm
>
> export SUBARCH=arm
>
> export PATH=~/arm-eabi-4.6/linux-x86/toolchain/arm-eabi-4.4.3/bin:$PATH
>
> export CROSS_COMPILE=arm-eabi-
>
> export PATH=$PATH:~/arm-eabi-4.6/darwin-x86/toolchain/arm-eabi-4.4.3
>
> bash              # execute the bash again to re-execute the ./bashrc file

Get goldfish kernel

> git clone https://android.googlesource.com/kernel/goldfish.git
>
> git checkout -t origin/android-goldfish-3.4 -b goldfish3.4

Configure and compile goldfish kernel

> gedit $GOLDFISH_KERNEL_PATH/arch/arm/configs/goldfish_armv7_defconfig
>
> Add 'CONFIG_DEBUG_INFO=y' to goldfish_armv7a_deconfig
>
> make goldfish_armv7_defconfig
>
> make -j8

Testing new built goldfish kernel

Now you can find the newly built kernel at $GOLDFISH_KERNEL_PATH/arch/arm/boot/*zImage*

also you need the ELF format of kernel since it contains the debug symbols needed by gdb: $GOLDFISH_KERNEL_PATH/*vmlinux*

**Start default android emulator with an instance of gdb server listening of 1234**

> emulator-arm.exe -verbose -show-kernel -netfast -avd test -qemu -S -gdb tcp::1234,ipv4 -kernel $GOLDFISH_KERNEL_PATH/arch/arm/boot/zImage

**Getting apprpriate gdb version - target should be android arm**

> Download gdb for windows: https://github.com/ikonst/gdb-7.7-android

**Copy vmlinx from kernel root folder to your windows machine**

**Start gdb using command line: gdb.exe %GOLDFISH_KERNEL_PATH/vmlinux**

> (gdb) Set remotetimeout 10
>
> (gdb) Set debug remote 1
>
> (gdb) Target remote localhost:1234
>
> (gdb) b sdhci_request
>
> (gdb) step
>
> (gdb) step
>
> (gdb) cont
>
> (gdb) etc ..

Comment: Hello, what version of Android studio did you use?

Comment: I use to build the emulator from scratch
https://android.googlesource.com/platform/external/qemu.git

Comment: I think it was - "0.10.50":

echo "#define QEMU_VERSION    \"0.10.50\"" >> $config_h